# Should I always use shared_ptr to create a class instance(instead of just new)?

Tags: c++, class, memory, std, shared-ptr

As wiki shows, `shared_ptr` can handle the heap space recycle problems.
So, I always use shared_ptr to create instance, is there any problems?

and I use it as this, i dont need to `delete s`, right?

```
s = std::shared_ptr<S>(new S).get();
```

Comment: Those are not your only two options. A naked `new` is rarely the best choice but you have other memory managing helpers. `std::unique_ptr` is often useful. If you have a lot of objects you can often leave the management to a [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) etc. It depends of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Well, you don't have to delete `s` in your example, it will be deleted for you right in the same line. `std::shared_ptr(new S)` creates temporary `shared_ptr` which lives for the time of expression evaluation and you don't assign it to any variable. So it get's destroyed right away. `shared_ptr` does not "handle the heap space recycle problems" magically, you still have to use it properly. Maybe unique_ptr is better? But the topic is too broad for comment or single answer. I'd recommend starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one

Comment: Use `unique_ptr` unless you actually need shared ownership.

Comment: C++ `shared_ptr` mimics the shared reference semantics of Java or C#, but in my experience with C++ it is much better to have a stricter ownership mode.  I recommend `unique_ptr` where possible, and `shared_ptr` if you *need* it rather than as your first option.

Comment: Do you actually need a pointer at all? Do `S s;` by default, unless you actually need it on the heap for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't *always* use `shared_ptr` because there are [more types of smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) than just `shared_ptr`. The Standard Library also provides `unique_ptr` for example. You must evaluate which better suits the task at hand.

Smart pointers in general are however the preferred way of safely handling dynamically allocated objects in modern C++.  As a general rule of thumb, avoid the use of `new` and `delete` unless you encounter a problem that can't be solved without them.

As an aside, your example will not work as you expect.

```
auto s = std::shared_ptr(new S).get();
```

This will create a dangling pointer. The call to `new` dynamically allocates an object of type `S`. A pointer to it is given to the constructor for `shared_ptr` which now manages the object lifetime. You then assign a copy of the raw pointer of `S` to `s` via `get()`. At the end of the line the `shared_ptr` destructor frees `S` meaning that whatever `s` points to is undefined.

The correct way to create a shared pointer would be:

```
auto s = std::make_shared<S>();
```

Comment: no new S in the brackets? and to get the instance, i should use s.get()?

Comment: You don't need to use `new` because `make_shared` does it internally, you're just telling the template what type the smart pointer should hold. The main benefit of letting the library handle it is that `shared_ptr`'s control block and the object itself will be allocated together. If you call the shared_ptr constructor with `new` you'll end up with the control block and object potentially allocated to different parts of the heap. Calls to `get()` are useful in some situations, for example if you need the raw pointer to pass to a C function.